# Deface::override how to add field in partial ? Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I created new field through migration, in table spree_users, but I don't how to add my new field in Deface::override...

i need added field phone in partial

**My override:**

Deface::Override.new(
    virtual_path: 'spree/admin/users/_lifetime_stats.html.erb',
    name: 'add_field_phone_to_',
    insert_after: "user-lifetime-stats",
    text: "*I dont now what to do...*")

**Partial _lifetime_stats.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= Spree.t(:) %>:</td>
  <td><%= pretty_time(@user.) %></td>
</tr>
```

**My decorator**

Spree::Order.class_eval do
end

**schema**

create_table "spree_users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|

t.string "phone", default: "", null: false

end

How does this relate ?
And is there documentation for deface:: override ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Deface documentation](https://github.com/spree/deface#source). You can specify `source: :partial` in the override.